# if then nested statements cause page not to load

Tags: php, if-statement

As per the suggestions of others I have added to the initial code. Same result:

I am having an issue with the following `if` statement.

When it finds results on either of the two conditions it works great and returns the results using the for each statement. If there are no results then the page doesn't load completely. I have tried using die; in a number of locations which did not improve the functions or make this work.

NEW CODE

```
if (!empty($query)) {
    foreach ($query as $available) {
        echo $available->column1 . "<br>\n";
    }
} elseif (empty($query)) {
    $query_plus->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT column1 FROM mytable"));
    foreach ($query as $available_plus_2) {
        echo $available_plus_2->column1 . "<br>\n";
    }
} elseif (!empty($query_plus)) {
    echo "nothing here";
}
```

Comment: Add this to the top of your program just after the <?php it will show all errors. ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Where do `$query` & `$query_plus` come from?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by doesn't load completely?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if statement with nested for each breaks page when there are no results, works when there are results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65430060/if-statement-with-nested-for-each-breaks-page-when-there-are-no-results-works-w)

Comment: @jasonk thanks. That showed me the error which allowed me to solve this myself. Working in WP it prevents many errors from being shown.

Comment: Your last question was closed for lack of detail. This one will likely go the same way. If you have new information you should edit it into the original question so that it can be reopened.

Comment: @steven thanks for taking the time. Thanks to jason I was able to get this working myself. To answer your question they are mysql queries of their own further up in the code. And as to the page not loading, its a fatal error and I literally meant the page stopped loading :)

Comment: @tangentiallyperpendicular thanks. That was my first question that someone closed while I was working with some nice people like yourself on solving it

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular there isnt any more detail to provide unless you can think of something. This was pretty straight forward. I have previously edited in more detail to questions and find it a waste of time since no one will ever reopen it. Its a pretty big flaw of this community.

Comment: @kris since you now appear to have solved the problem there is, at least, an answer. It's ok to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!empty($query)) {
    foreach ($query as $available) {
        echo $available->column1 . "<br>\n";
    }
} elseif (empty($query)) {
    $query_plus=$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT column1 FROM mytable"));
    foreach ($query as $available_plus_2) {
        echo $available_plus_2->column1 . "<br>\n";
    }
} elseif (!empty($query_plus)) {
    echo "nothing here";
}
```

The $wpdb-> is necessary before the prepare. Since WP is very bad at error reporting adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the functions page will allow all fatal errors to be seen